# Excel to SQL Server through SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

So, I'm trying to ingest *one* spreadsheet and it's working in dev, not in production..  here are the specs:

Dev: 64 bit OS, Project setting: 64 bit runtime = true, Delay Validation setting on the connection manager is false, and no Access Database Engine is installed.

Production: 64 bit OS, Project setting: 64 bit runtime = false...but changed to true and it still would not work.  Delay Validation setting on the connection manager is false (changed to true and it still would not work).  32 bit Access Database Runtime 2010 is installed.

The Excel file is Excel 2013.

---

I have the 2016 Database runtimes...both 32 and 64 bit, and I can probably get the production admins to uninstall what they have, bounce the server, and reinstall using what I can give them.

---

So where am I going wrong here?  How do I get production to read this file?

Comment: what are the details of the error message? do you have the `Connection Expression or Excel File Path` set for the excel file?

Comment: The error message is that the package cannot acquire a managed connection to the source.  The file path is set for the file.

Comment: what is the file connection expression? is that on the `Shared drive`? If so, use `UNC` path

Comment: No, it's not on a shared drive.

Comment: Probably on Production you don't have the correct path to the file.  If you think you do, please post screenshots that prove it.

Comment: Yeah, I do.  I don't control the production server, but the production dbas make sure to put all submitted input for my group into the exact same directory, and they double check everything.

Answer (score 0):

In production, set 64 bit runtime = false and Delay Validation = true. If this doesn't help, please share the error that you receive.